# use different baselines to query data

Tags: java, python, sql, excel, ms-access

I have data which looks like this:

```
data_
company      result        ID    group
cars         50            q1    ground
boats        0             q1    water
bicycles     50            q2    ground
cars         75            q2    water 
horses       0             q2    ground
foxes        50            q5    ground
.....etc
```

So I want to ask the following question:

Which Ground companies have a result that differs from the Cars company and during which quarter (ID) did this occur?

In essence the result above would be:

```
horses, q2 (result: 0, differs from cars 75)
bicycles, q2 (result: 50, differs from cars 75)
```

I'm using Excel or Access to do this. But if anyone have a better suggestion, I would be happy to hear it.

I feel I can manage a semi-automatic method in Excel, fetching the baseline data and then asking questions using a combination of VLOOKUP and IF-formula. So something like this:

```
baseline_
company    result   id 
cars       50       q1
cars       75       q2
```

Then asking: which Q1 ground-groups had a result different from 50? And which Q2 ground-groups had a result different from 75?

Even splitting it like this, is a possibility:

```
groups_ground
company    result    id
cars       etc.      etc.
foxes      etc.      etc.
horses     etc.      etc.
bicycles   etc.      etc.
```

But all these methods are a bit tedious, given my data is 500k+ rows.

SQL I'm thinking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM data_ D
 LEFT JOIN baseline_ B
 ON D.result=!B.result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is along the right lines.  But you need to look for matches and then choose the ones that don't match, so it requires more conditions:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM data d LEFT JOIN
     data dcars
     ON d.result = dcars.result and
        dcars.company = 'cars'
WHERE d.group = 'ground' and
      dcars.company is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['cars',         50,            'q1',    'ground'],
        ['boat',        0,             'q1',    'water'],
        ['bicycles',     50,            'q2',    'ground'],
        ['cars',         75,            'q2',    'water'],
        ['horses',      0,             'q2',    'ground'],
        ['foxes',        50,            'q5',    'ground']]
data_dict = {i[2]: i[1] for i in data if i[0] == 'cars'}
for i in data:
    if i[3] == 'ground' and i[0] != 'cars':
        if i[2] != data_dict.get(i[2]):
            print("{}, {} (result: {}, differs from cars {})".format(i[0], i[2], i[1], data_dict.get(i[2])))
```

result:

```
bicycles, q2 (result: 50, differs from cars 75)
horses, q2 (result: 0, differs from cars 75)
foxes, q5 (result: 50, differs from cars None)
```